# Custom HTML Element Tag within React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're using a component library which uses custom elements. This requires us to use custom HTML tags within our JSX. For a very simple example:

```
var App = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       return <niner/>;
   }
});

React.render(
        <App/>,
        document.getElementById('content')
);
```

In this particular case, I just need React to output a `niner` tag without it trying to do anything too special with it. I intentionally have no niner React component.

According to [JSX in depth](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html),

> React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish between local component classes and HTML tags.

Which led me to believe that ReactJS would just treat `<niner/>` as a regular HTML tag and not choke on it. When I run the code above, however, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined 10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js:94
createSourceCodeErrorMessage 10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js:141
transformCode 10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js:187 
run 10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js:242
check 10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js:295
loadScripts 10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js:324 
runScripts
```

Do I need to do some sort of wizardry to get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. I just tried this

```
var ComponentExample = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
          <niner>This is a niner element</niner>
      )
    }
});


React.render(<ComponentExample/>, mountNode);
```

So no you would not need any wizardry to get it to work. Maybe it's a problem with the way you bundle?

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Ramon. They recently added support for this so wizardry is no longer required (as you've noted).

Comment: is this always safe to use?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to do something like

```js
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<niner/>'}} />
```

so,

```js
var App = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<niner/>'}} />;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @zackify. I sure hope not, but I appreciate the response!

Comment: It's the only thing you can do.